# OverlayManager Error. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I am trying to use the Overlay Manager for Autodesk Forge Viewer V7. When calling `overlayManager.addScene('my_scene')` I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined.

It doesn't seem like overlayScenes is ever defined, but addScene calls `this.impl.overlayscenes.hasOwnProperty`

I created an extension and called the following code in the constructor of my extension:

```
function ClickableMarkup() {

    Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.call(this, viewer, options);
    let overlayManager = new 
    Autodesk.Viewing.OverlayManager();

    // Add scene -> Throws Error
    overlayManager.addScene('my_scene');

}
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try pass the current Viewer's implementation object in to properly initialize the manager:

```
let overlayManager = new 
    Autodesk.Viewing.OverlayManager(viewer.impl);
```